# Какие есть ограничения в Discord?

Tags: discord

Пишу диплом и он затрагивает тему создания сервера в Discord. Ни как не могу на практике проверить работают ли пара пунктов.

Что мне интересно узнать:

1. Сколько всего человек может быть на голосовом канале? Есть ли в этом ограничение.
2. Сколько всего может быть голосовых **активных** каналов на сервере?
3. Сколько человек может быть в видео-канале? Что если 1-2 человека будет с камерой а остальные нет, увеличится ли возможное количество?
4. Сколько всего на сервере может быть **активных** Видео-каналов?

Answer (score 2):

1. Не более 200 человек на один голосовой чат. Есть ручное ограничение до 99 человек либо меньше.
2. Сервер может иметь не более 500 каналов - текстовые, голосовые каналы и категории также засчитываются. После того, как 500 каналов достигнуты, создать каналы больше нельзя.
3. Да столько же, сколько и в голосовом. Это ведь один и тот же чат, можно считать это в некотором смысле стримом.
4. Второй пункт.

Но я могу и ошибаться, так что всю информацию ты сможешь найти здесь: https://discordik.ru/instrukcii/maksimalnoe-kolichestvo-uchastnikov-videokonferencii-discord/

P.S. На ограничения также влияет Nitro Boost.

Answer (score 0):

1. Новый тип каналов "Сцена" (Study) не имеет каких-либо ограничений на количество единовременно находящихся в голосовом канале пользователей. Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](https://support.discord.com/hc/ru/articles/1500005513722-%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BE-%D0%A1%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-Stage-Channels-)
2. 500 каналов, в том числе категории, текстовые, страницы "Store", Stage и announcements (каналы с иконкой рупора).
3. На одном сервере максимум можно запустить 50 трансляций экрана.